# Accessing parent route slug from route

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a route `/settings/:setting_id/overview`. In my `settings.js` route I can see the value of `setting_id` in the model function, i.e.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        alert(params.setting_id);
    }
});
```

However, in my `settings/overview.js` route I get `undefined` for `setting_id` for the exact same code as above.

My `router.js` is defined as follows:

```
Router.map(function() {
    //...
    this.resource('settings', { path: 'settings/:settings_id' }, function() {
        this.route('overview');
        // ...
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using the [modelFor](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_modelFor) methid for accessing to the parent model in your current route.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.modelFor('settings').get('id');
    }
});
```